# Unable to get iptables owner module (gid-owner) to work

Tags: iptables, group

On my ubuntu 16.04 laptop, I'm trying to setup the `iptables` rules so that internet access is denied to all applications by default, and allowed to only one group called `internet`. I won't add that group to my own login, but use `sudo -g` or `sg` to access internet whenever I want. For example:

```
sudo -g internet firefox
```

or

```
sg internet -c "firefox"
```

However, this approach isn't working. Following is the `iptables` rule that I've added:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80  -m owner --gid-owner internet   -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443  -m owner --gid-owner internet   -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53  -m owner --gid-owner internet   -j ACCEPT
```

I've tested the above rules, when I remove the owner module, it works perfectly and internet is allowed to all applications. But when I add the owner module and `gid-owner` filter, no app is able to access the internet (even using the mentioned `sg` and `sudo -g` commands).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding ``iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG`` to log any dropped packet and compare it with your rule? You may also try using nc or telnet (i.e. "telnet 8.8.8.8 53") to check if it works.

Comment: I've tried both telnet and ping - neither works with the gid filter set, but after removing that, both work. Don't think logging would be of any use as I already know its out right rejecting the packages.

Comment: Logging may help you to investigate this issue. Your scenario worked for me (I just checked) so I think that logs along with ``iptables -L`` may help.

Comment: btw, here is my scenario on virtualbox. I denied for anyone but root, and it works: https://pastebin.com/TVQTV2gP

Comment: Did you try with ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: ``Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64)``, fully updated

Comment: I'm running a newer kernel (`4.8.0-56-generic #61~16.04.1-Ubuntu`), I think that could be the reason. I also tested the same scenario in a Debian 9.0 VM (4.9 kernel) and it worked there! So my guess is that the owner module isn't supported on this kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much trial and error, I was able to find the answer to my own question. The issue wasn't with iptables or with Ubuntu/Linux version I was using, but rather, the issue was with this third rule:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53  -m owner --gid-owner internet   -j ACCEPT
```

Since `udp/53` port is used for DNS name resolution, background services like `dnsmasq` could be using them, hence name resolution wasn't happening when I tried to run a program with the `internet` group as these other services weren't in that group. However, ideally those services should still have had access to the port since they are running under root account (<s>and root can do anything!</s>), but the design of iptables owner module seems not to respect such root privileges.

As soon as I removed the owner module check from this last rule, the internet started working:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

**Edit**

Another, not directly linked, but related issue is using the owner module for root group. We are inclined to assign the root group access to the internet (in addition to or instead of the `internet` group) like this:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80  -m owner --gid-owner root   -j ACCEPT
```

However, this doesn't work in practice because a lot many apps don't use the root user to connect to the internet for security reasons. For example, the following command won't work even after doing the above:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That's because `apt` program internally uses the `_apt` user to download packages for security reasons.

Comment: that's why I asked you to telnet to 8.8.8.8 by IP, not by name;)

Comment: > That's because `apt` program internally uses the `_apt` user to download packages for security reasons.

I owe you a huge beer!
Please tell me how did you find out that?

Comment: @tymik Glad you found this helpful! It has been many years since but from what I recall, it was `netstat` or similar unix command which gave me the PID of the apt process along with the user that was running it.

Comment: Thanks! I digged a bit in the meantime and this is in the [source code](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/f557a5e15bb4715557566d7e88e7367c17e94ebf/apt-pkg/init.cc#L187-L188) explicitly

Answer (score 7):

Already marked solved, but for the sanity of anyone else running into this issue, I thought I'd elaborate here and explain the actual cause of the problem you discovered. The issue is with **iptables**. Specifically, it does not handle group ID filtering as us humans expect it to. I'm not sure if it's WAD or a bug. IMHO, it's a bug in the **iptables** `-m owner` extension code.

The issue is with the handling of `--gid-owner`. It appears the **iptables extensions** code does not filter the group id literally (i.e. is user in this group, yes or no?). It's apparent from the module's behavior that it digs deeper and examines the username settings, and then makes a decision based on primary group membership of the user. That is versus a literal examination of the list of group members (expected by myself and others who've had this problem). This behavior is not documented in any of the relevant man pages.

To wit, Ubuntu's implementation of iptables only examines the *primary group* of the owner of the current network packet. Let's say you wish to create a split VPN, where a specific user group *vpn* will have its traffic forced to the VPN interface.

If you were to specify each owner, the `--uid-owner` parameter under the `-m owner` extension will work as expected. Then let's say you have multiple usernames that you want to branch, and the user list may change over time. So, you decide it would be more efficient to use group id filtering instead (`--gid-owner`). You place all your VPN traffic users into a single group called *vpn* and change the iptables parameter to `--gid-owner vpn`. As you've seen, in many cases the filter fails to perform as expected. Why?

Only the primary/default group of the owner of the packet will be compared. Therefore, any username you added to your *vpn* group after the user was created will be in the *vpn* group as a secondary user, and ***they won't be branched even though they are a member of the group!***

The reason the 'root' user didn't work for you is because its primary/default group is 'root'.

**Illustrated Example**

Say you have username *vpn* in primary group *vpn* and username *testdummy* in primary group *test* but *testdummy* is also a member of the *vpn* group. To *testdummy*, *vpn* is a secondary group.

This iptables rule will mark packets belonging to the *vpn* user but not the *testdummy* user, even though instinctively one would think packets from both users would be marked because they both belong to group *vpn*:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! -d 192.168.1.1 -m owner --gid-owner vpn -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

To solve the problem, you will have to create another rule, such as this solution:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! -d 192.168.1.1 -m owner --gid-owner vpn -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! -d 192.168.1.1 -m owner --uid-owner testdummy -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you! I struggling with this problem... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/738915/linux-iptables-accept-group-not-working . If you have 2 minutes, can you please get a look at it? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--suppl-groups` for this, added in [ea6cc2fd](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ea6cc2fd8a2b89ab6dcd096ba6dbc1ecbdf26564). From [`iptables-extensions(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html):

```
   --suppl-groups
          Causes group(s) specified with --gid-owner to be also checked in
          the supplementary groups of a process.
```

See also [iptables group matching: modifying the primary group of a user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/691404/164143)

Answer (score -2):

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80  -m owner ! --gid-owner root -j DROP
```

Comment: welcome to U&L, can you please elaborate your answer ? like meaning of flags, etc ..