# iptables group matching: modifying the primary group of a user

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm trying to configure network access restrictions specific to a group of users on Debian 11 using the command `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner APIGROUP -j REJECT`.

Here `APIGROUP` is a group. The users present in this group should be rejected in the `OUTPUT` chain. But when I go through the forum I read that this group is referring to the primary group of a user.

Is it good practice to change the primary group of the user? Are there any impacts on the permissions of those users?

Is there any way to achieve what I want using iptables?

References:

- https://serverfault.com/q/550276/439930
- [Unable to get iptables owner module (gid-owner) to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373703/271783)

Comment: Regarding *"Is it good practice to change the primary group of the user? Are there any impacts on the permissions of those users?"*, the main effect of changing the primary gid is that any files or directories created by the user will have the group of his primary gid. If those files have certain access (read/write/execute) to group and not all, users that don't belong to this group won't be able to access them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature already exists: [`--suppl-groups`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#suppl).

Recent Linux kernels have a newer feature allowing to match the supplementary groups. It was added to solve OP's category of problem in [kernel 5.3](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.3#Networking) mid 2019 so is already available in Debian 11's 5.10.x kernel.

> - Netfilter
>
>   [...]
>   xt_owner: Add supplementary groups option [commit](https://git.kernel.org/linus/ea6cc2fd8a2b89ab6dcd096ba6dbc1ecbdf26564)

The matching update to iptables exists [since 1.8.4](https://lwn.net/Articles/806180/) so is available in Debian 11's 1.8.7:

> iptables-legacy:
>
> - Add --suppl-groups option to owner match.

As [documented](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#suppl) in manual:

> `--suppl-groups`
>
> Causes group(s) specified with `--gid-owner` to be also checked in the
> supplementary groups of a process.

the syntax becomes (it appears to be mandatory to put `--suppl-groups` *after* `--gid-owner APIGROUP`):

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner APIGROUP --suppl-groups -j REJECT
```

Note: this appears to be a rare case where *iptables* recently received a new feature but *nftables* didn't receive it: this doesn't appear to be currently available with *nftables*. As it's an [xtables](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XTABLES.html) feature, as usual it's still [usable by `iptables-nft`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_COMPAT.html) in addition to `iptables-legacy`.

Comment: Just a little question, Is this feature supported by centos 7 also?

Comment: That's part of the reasons I wrote when and on what version it was added: so other readers know if it's available. CentOS7 runs kernel 3.10.x so it won't. RHEL8/Rocky Linux 8 runs kernel 4.18.x so wouldn't either, but as Redhat backports a lot of features, it might exist, but I wouldn't count on it.