# Linux iptables ACCEPT group not working

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to lock a Linux laptop (IN and OUTPUT). So, a software should be allowed to connect to internet ONLY if is launched by a specific group. After reading many (many) posts and came to this solution, but it's not working.
This is what I did to test the OUTPUT. (If I can make it work, I'll do the same for INPUT.)

Downloaded firefox.tar.bz2 and extracted in path/to/my/folder

First, in the GUI, I went to Menu/Administration/Users and groups, created a new group "freegroup" and added the only user on the laptop "myself" to the group. If I click on the user I can see in groups that the second group is "freegroup"

1. Turn off GUFW (in the GUI)
2. Make sure we start empty:

   `sudo iptables -F`

   `sudo iptables --delete-chain`
3. List rules :

   `sudo iptables -L -n`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination       

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

4. Add rule for group "freegroup", and make sure to add the supplementary group option:

   `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner freegroup --suppl-groups -j ACCEPT`
5. Close the OUTPUT

   `sudo iptables --policy OUTPUT DROP`
6. List new rules
   `sudo iptables -L -n --line-numbers`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner GID match 1001 incl. suppl. groups
```

7. Run Firefox from Terminal as group "freegroup" :

   `sudo -g freegroup -s path/to/my/folder/firefox`

Firefox fires up, but can't connect to the internet...

I only see the error in Terminal
`ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.`, but I don't think it's related to iptables...

What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to Linux. Pls help don't downvote!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: I see you've poked me [on my Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997523/iptables-drop-all-but-group/997525?noredirect=1#comment2550792_997525).  I am assuming you did not read my last paragraph on my answer stating that this 100% WILL mess with `sudo`, superuser, system services, etc.?  also, launching the application as a different group via `sudo` is NOT going to be a guarantee way of testing this, you need a separate user that gets covered by this policy for testing with that user being a member of the group.

Comment: CROSSPOSTED: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458243/iptables-drop-software-if-not-run-by-a-specific-group-not-working - pick only ONE site and post there, do not cross post as it is considered noisy and there's overlap between Ask Ubuntu and Unix and Linux such that you don't benefit by crossposting.

Comment: Looks like a warning message, not an error message. Aside from that, I am very rusty on my iptables knowledge as I have not worked with it directly in quite a while. This resource may be helpful to you: https://datahacker.blog/industry/technology-menu/networking/routes-and-rules